# Using openURL to send an email from Yahoo Mail client

Tags: ios, yahoo, url-scheme, openurl

What are the openURL parameters for Yahoo Mail?

"ymail:" appears to work, but it just simply opens up the application. I can't seem to figure out how to pre-fill the recipient address.

Comment: It seems to be a custom app. It depends only on its developers of what URL schemes they support. I would recommend to contact their team, never worked with this application before actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
"ymail://mail/compose?subject=Subject&to=email@gmail.com&body=message_content"
```

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
if let appSettings = URL(string:"ymail://mail/compose?subject=Subject&to=email@gmail.com&body=message_content") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, completionHandler: { (success) in})
        }
```

Don't forget to add `"ymail"` into `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your  Info.plist